# Android application signed with same key store using same sharedUserId crashes due to java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, process, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I want to make some Android applications running in the same process, so I give those apps's `AndroidManifest` the same sharedUserId:

```
< manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  ...  
  android:sharedUserId="aaa.bbb" >
```

and assign each apps's application the same process:

```
< application
    ...
    android:process="com.mytest" >
```

It works in `android 4.4.4` , all the Applications run in the same Process.

But crash happened in `android 6.0.1`. 
When I run the second app, it crashes due to:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}:
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" on path:
  DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

after the system kill the Process, the second app can run and crashes if I run the first application.

It seem that applications can not run in the same process in the same time and I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Each APK has its own `ClassLoader`. An [article](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.fr/2009/06/controlling-application-separation.html) talking about this.

So it's normal you can't access a class of another APK.
It seems that a security bug was fix between Kitkat and Marshmallow.

Why you need this system ?
If it's to share data between application, you could use `ContentProvider`
If it's to launch `Activity` or `Service`, you could use Intent with action.

Comment: Thank you ! I read the article. Each Application has a WebView, I want to share the cookies by CookieManager because it is singleton. Maybe there is another way to solve it, but I just  want to know how can I shared process in Marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it !
disable the options in Android studio ant it works !
[image]